# How to get array from blade template in jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

What i want is to get an array of input values in jquery.

```
  @foreach ($view_360s as $view_360)

          <input type="text" name="iframe_title[]" class="form_input iframe_title" value="{{$view_360->title}}" />

       @endforeach
```

When i do like this i get only first value and its not in array.

```
$('.iframe_title').val()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a better idea to pass a collection of objects as json. Something like this:

```
<input id="view_360s" type="hidden" value="{{ $view_360s->toJson() }}">
```

And then get the collection and iterate over it:

```
$('#view_360s').each(....)
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('. iframe_title').each(function(i, obj) {
    console.log($(obj).val())
});
```